# can't get the href from the HTML anchor tag while scrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I 'm trying to scrap https://www.goflink.com/de-DE/shop/, and I've got the div link successfully, but failing to get the href from the anchor tags.
I'm working on getting the links of the product categories
and I get this error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[52], line 3
      1 productlinks = []
      2 for product in productlist:
----> 3     link = product.find("a",{"class":"category swimlane-item"}).get('href')              
      4     productlinks.append(baseurl + link)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Thanks in advance.

```
%pip install beautifulsoup4 
%pip install requests
%pip install pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl = "https://www.goflink.com/de-DE/shop/"
# baseurl = "https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}
k = requests.get('https://www.goflink.com/de-DE/shop/').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')
productlist = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"swimlane"})
print(productlist)
productlinks = []
for product in productlist:
    link = product.find("a",{"class":"category swimlane-item"}).get('href')              
    productlinks.append(baseurl + link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to search for a div with class "swimlane" to start, you can just search for all the "a" classes directly.
The original error occurred because the product.find was returning None, there wasn't a problem with the .get('href') code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl = "https://www.goflink.com/de-DE/shop/"
# baseurl = "https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}
k = requests.get('https://www.goflink.com/de-DE/shop/').text
soup=BeautifulSoup(k,'html.parser')
productlist = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"category swimlane-item"})
#print(productlist)
productlinks = []
for product in productlist:
    link = product.get('href')
    print(link)
    productlinks.append(baseurl + link)
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)
Also, I'm having difficulties in extracting the image url from the items' page, for example this one https://www.goflink.com/de-DE/shop/product/burger-vegane-maultaschen-300g-11012811/
Find method returns none on searching for the source Tag or the parent div with the class.
Thanks in advance :)